# Динамическое заполнение двумерного массива в Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

Одномерный массив можно удобно заполнять прямиком в коде:

```
var array = emptyArray<String>()
array += "строка"
```

Но в ситуации с двумерным массивом `var array = Array(7, {emptyArray<String>()})` я не нашел информации, как можно так же удобно заполнить массив без прибегания к счетчикам и прочим костылям. `array[position] += "строка"` уже не сработает. Как решить данную проблему?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел ответ на свой же вопрос: 
для данной идеи я использую `MutableList`

```
var timetable = Array(7, { mutableListOf<String>()})
```

И в коде можно просто добавить значение к необходимой строке:

```
timetable[position].add(value)
```

Answer (score 1):

Либо так

```
array[position] = array[position] + "строка"
```

Либо написать свой сеттер для конкретной реализации двумерного массива

```
private operator fun Array<Array<String>>.set(i: Int, value: String) {
    this[i] = this[i] + value
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но я нашел немного более простое решение с использованием MutableList:
var timetable = Array(7, { mutableListOf<String>()})
И теперь, чтобы добавить значение, необходимо: 
timetable[position].add(value)

Comment: Была у меня и такая версия, но это уже массив списков получается :)

Comment: по сути, это мне и требовалось, но все равно спасибо за ответ)
Кому-нибудь да пригодится